# Cassandra pod fails after kubernetes node restart

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, datastax

I have successfully installed dse in my kubernetes environment using the Kubernetes Operator instructions:

With nodetool I checked that all pod successfully joined the ring

The problem is that when I reboot one of the kubernetes node the cassandra pod that was running on that node never recover:

```
[root@node1 ~]# kubectl exec -it -n cassandra cluster1-dc1-r2-sts-0 -c cassandra nodetool status
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving/Stopped
-- Address Load Tokens Owns (effective) Host ID Rack
UN 10.244.166.132 153.82 KiB 1 77.9% 053cc18e-397c-4abe-bb1b-d48a3fef3c93 r3
DS 10.244.104.1 136.09 KiB 1 26.9% 8ae31e1c-856e-44a8-b081-c5c040b535b9 r1
UN 10.244.135.2 202.8 KiB 1 95.2% 06200794-298c-4122-b8ff-4239bc7a8ded r2

[root@node1 ~]# kubectl get pods -n cassandra
NAME READY STATUS RESTARTS AGE
cass-operator-56f5f8c7c-w6l2c 1/1 Running 0 17h
cluster1-dc1-r1-sts-0 1/2 Running 2 17h
cluster1-dc1-r2-sts-0 2/2 Running 0 17h
cluster1-dc1-r3-sts-0 2/2 Running 0 17h
```

I have looked into the logs but I can't figure out what is the problem.

The "kubectl logs"" command return the logs below:

```
INFO  [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] 2020-03-25 12:13:13,536 Cli.java:555 - address=/192.168.0.11:38590 url=/api/v0/probes/liveness status=200 OK
INFO  [epollEventLoopGroup-6506-1] 2020-03-25 12:13:14,110 Clock.java:35 - Could not access native clock (see debug logs for details), falling back to Java system clock
WARN  [epollEventLoopGroup-6506-2] 2020-03-25 12:13:14,111 Slf4JLogger.java:146 - Unknown channel option 'TCP_NODELAY' for channel '[id: 0x8a898bf3]'
WARN  [epollEventLoopGroup-6506-2] 2020-03-25 12:13:14,116 Loggers.java:28 - [s6501] Error connecting to /tmp/dse.sock, trying next node
java.io.FileNotFoundException: null
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:110)
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.connect(Socket.java:257)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect0(AbstractEpollChannel.java:732)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollDomainSocketChannel.doConnect(EpollDomainSocketChannel.java:87)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.connect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:559)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1366)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.connect(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:47)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ConnectInitHandler.connect(ConnectInitHandler.java:57)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:512)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1024)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:276)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$3.run(Bootstrap.java:252)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:375)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
INFO  [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] 2020-03-25 12:13:14,118 Cli.java:555 - address=/192.168.0.11:38592 url=/api/v0/probes/readiness status=500 Internal Server Error
```

The error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: null` appears also when cassandra starts successfully.

So what remains is the error:

```
address=/192.168.0.11:38592 url=/api/v0/probes/readiness status=500 Internal Server Error
```

Which doesn't say much to me.

The "kubectl describe" shows the following

```
Warning Unhealthy 4m41s (x6535 over 18h) kubelet, node2 Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
```

In the cassandra container only this process is running:

````
java -Xms128m -Xmx128m -jar /opt/dse/resources/management-api/management-api-6.8.0.20200316-LABS-all.jar --dse-socket /tmp/dse.sock --host tcp://0.0.0.0```
````

And in the `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` I can't point out any error

Comment: Please, can you describe the pod that is failing and update your question with the output? Command is `kubectl describe pod POD_NAME`. You can also check pod lgs and post here if relevant, `kubectl logs POD_NAME` where POD_NAME is the name of the problematic pod.

Comment: ok, thanks. I have added more details

Comment: Try giving Cassandra more than a 128MB heap.  In fact, I think 2GB is the minimum, and (depending on the expected workload) it should really have at least 4GB-8GB.

Answer (score 4):

Andrea, the error "java.io.FileNotFoundException: null" is a harmless message about a transient error during the Cassandra pod starting up and healthcheck.

I was able to reproduce the issue you ran into. If you run `kubectl get pods` you should see the affected pod showing 1/2 under "READY" column, this means the Cassandra container was not brought up in the auto-restarted pod. Only the management API container is running. I suspect this is a bug in the operator and I'll work with the developers to sort it out.

As a workaround you can run `kubectl delete pod/<pod_name>` to recover your Cassandra cluster back to a normal state (in your case `kubectl delete pod/cluster1-dc1-r1-sts-0`). This will redeploy the pod and remount the data volume automatically, without losing anything.

Comment: While helping individuals, we also try to produce a permanent source of future help for others - so answers that produce a tangible record are preferred. Before offering 1:1 help, read [this Meta post](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280603) and reconsider making the effort to document the answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the meta post, very helpful guidance.

Comment: The delete in my test system didn't help to recover:

Comment: Andrea, I tested the process of `kubectl delete pod/pod_name` before sending the answer above and it worked for me. If you want, you can find my contact information in my profile to setup a time for me to take a look at your cluster. After we figure out the proper solution, I will share in this thread for future help for others.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I don't know how I could contact you, in the profile I don't see any mail.

Comment: @weideng I believe I have figured out when the work-around works and when it doesn't. It works only when the rebooting kube node is not the one where the seed node was running. It seems that the seed node is always one node and when the work-around doesn't work the  "kubectl get ep" return none endpoint for cluster1-seed-service.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when CoreDNS pods were not running on the node, on which I had started Cassandra. The DNS resolutions were not working properly. So, debugging network connectivity may help.